# how to compare date using moment in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am using `moment js` in angular to compare date .I am selecting first date from `type="date"` and second is hard corded string in date format. I want to compare both using moment lib on button click .
I tried link this

https://plnkr.co/edit/RgpjNMFCA03A5quITpoz?p=preview

```
$scope.check = function(){
    //alert('==')
    var time1 = "20-06-2017";
    var time2 =moment($scope.dateV,"MM-DD-YYYY");
    console.log(time2)
  }
```

I want to check is dates are equal or not ?

Comment: What's the criteria for the comparison you want to do?

Comment: mean they are equal or not date are equal or not

Comment: You can check my answer and let me know how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to [parse](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) your date strings (according to the format you need them to be in) and then use moment's [`isSame`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) function to check whether the two dates are same or not.

```
var time1 = moment("20-06-2017", "DD-MM-YYYY");
var time2 = moment($scope.dateV, "DD-MM-YYYY");
console.log(moment(time1).isSame(time2))
```

Hope this helps :)

PS - Updated a fork of your [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xf4GZrPS6KM3MBqvKSBH?p=preview) code